# What's the difference when time delay specified in LHS or RHS?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
a = #5 b;
#5 a = b;
```

Is there any difference between above 2 statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` on the RHS is known as an intra-assignment delay.  Read about the distinction in the IEEE Std (1800-2009), section 9.4.5 "Intra-assignment timing controls".

> An intra-assignment delay or event
>   control shall delay the assignment of
>   the new value to the left-hand side,
>   but the right-hand expression shall be
>   evaluated before the delay, instead of
>   after the delay.

Run a simulation with both statements to see what difference (if any) you observe.  Use `$monitor` and `$time`.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise that second statement doesn't specify a timing delay on the LHS of the blocking assignment. It is prefixed by a procedural_timing_control construct which can used before any type of procedural statement, not just assignment statements.